# Google map update cluster marker icon from url

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using cluster manager to render pins on the map, all pin item has it's own icon url and I should set icon from url. For the first render everything works fine. But I need to update some marker icons on click event or something. I have custom cluster renderer where I set custom icon dynamically and it works

```
....

override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: T, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
    try {
        val pin = item as OfferPinItem
        markerOptions?.icon(getDefaultPinIcon(pin.isClicked, pin.isSelected))
        pin.loadPinIconWithCallback(context, pin.isClicked) {
            markerOptions?.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(it))
        }
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions)

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Log.e("map", ex.toString())
    }
}
.....
```

when I need to update only markers icon , I using following logic :

```
 data.map { pin ->
    pin.isClicked = pin.id == highlightedPin

        if (clusterManager.markerCollection != null) {
            val existingMarker =
                clusterManager.markerCollection.markers.firstOrNull { m -> m.position == pin.getPosition() }
            if (existingMarker != null) {
                updateMarkerIcon(context, existingMarker, pin, pin.isClicked)
            }
    }
    pin
}
```

after calling those code sometimes two icons appear in on point :( one is before clicked icon (default icon) and second is active icon

Also I tried to call only re-cluster icons, but onBeforeClusterItemRendered is not called second times :

```
 clusterManager.clearItems()
    clusterManager.addItems(filteredItems)
    clusterManager.cluster()
```